# ¿Cómo usar una variable en diferentes archivos en Golang?

Tags: go

Suponiendo que tengo mi proyecto con la siguiente estructura:

```
/mi-proyecto
  main.go
  /rutas
    main.go
    /software
      software.go
```

Quiero declarar una variable en el archivo `main.go` del directorio `/rutas` para poder utilizarla en el archivo `software.go` del directorio `/rutas/software`.

Por ejemplo:

```
nombre := "Akko"
```

Declaro la variable `nombre` en `/rutas/main.go`

```
func Saludar() {
  fmt.Printf("Hola, %v\n", nombre)
}
```

Utilizo la variable nombre en `/rutas/software/software.go`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pues si se puede, usando go modules que viene en go 1.11 e hice un ejemplo en [gist](https://gist.github.com/kiramishima/25e70990d8b995c2e2cf1292460d18f4) , que no me dejo crear con el mismo nombre pero va comentada la referencia. Lo que si no se podría es crear una desde el main principal, para ello lo recomendable sería crear un archivo de go con esas configuraciones para llamarlas desde cualquier parte. Puedes consultar más sobre los módulos [aquí](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) , en el ejemplo aplique:

```
> go mod init mi-proyecto
```

Saludos :-)

Comment: Muchas gracias, Kira.